# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ext-modules/fleet/jsFleetController.js' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

am getting "Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ext-modules/fleet/jsFleetController.js' is not a function, got undefined" this error message when ever I load the template file.

The following are the code, please can anyone say what is wrong in the code. Thank you.

---

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Truck Trackers</title>


    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="main/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="ext-modules/fleet/jsFleet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="ext-modules/drivers/jsDrivers.css" rel="stylesheet" />



    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>


    <script src="main/appModule.js"></script>
    <script src="main/appRouting.js"></script>

    <script src="ext-modules/fleet/jsFleetModule.js"></script>
    <script src="ext-modules/fleet/jsFleetController.js"></script>

    <script src="ext-modules/drivers/jsDriversModule.js"></script>
    <script src="ext-modules/drivers/jsDriversController.js"></script>


    <script src="services/trucksService.js"></script>

</head>
<body class="container-fluid">
    <header class="js-title-bar">

                <div class="js-logo-area">
                    <img class="js-icon" ng-src="http://nebula.wsimg.com/eef77b1aea4eaf8d6ef180c127ac9733?AccessKeyId=FEE0E7FB4235C78BAABD&disposition=0&alloworigin=1" />
                    <div class="js-title-area">
                        <p class="js-logo-title"> <strong>Truck Tracker's</strong></p>
                        <p class="js-logo-subtitle">Where ever you GO, we FIND you !</p>
                    </div>   
            </div>

    </header>

        <div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**myApp Module**

```
"use strict";

angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute","jsFleet","jsDrivers"]);
```

---

**myApp Routing**

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/main', {
        templateUrl: 'main/main.html',

    })
    .when('/fleet', {

        controller: 'ext-modules/fleet/jsFleetController.js',
        templateUrl: 'ext-modules/fleet/jsFleetTemplate.html'
    })
        .when('/drivers', {
            controller: 'ext-modules/drivers/jsDriversController.js',
            templateUrl: 'ext-modules/drivers/jsDriversTemplate.html'

        })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/main' });
});
```

---

**main.HTML**

```
<div class="icon-bar" href="#/main" >

    <a href="#/fleet" class="item">
        <i class="fa fa-truck" style="font-size:48px;"></i>
        <label>Fleet</label>
    </a>

         <a href="#/drivers" class="item">
             <i class="fa fa-users" style="font-size:48px;"></i>
             <label>Drivers</label>
         </a>

         </div>
```

---

**jsFleet Module**

```
"use strict";    
angular.module("jsFleet", []);
```

---

**jsFleet Template**

```
<div class="panel1 panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading" align="center">TRUCKS</div>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">

                <tr>
                    <th>TruckID</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Dest.</th>
                    <th>Alerts</th>
                </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in trucks">
                <td>{{row.truckID}}</td>
                <td>{{row.status}}</td>
                <td>{{row.destination}}</td>
                <td>{{row.alerts}}</td>
            </tr>      

        </table>
    </div>
```

---

**jsFleet Controller**

```
"use strict";

angular.module("jsFleet").controller("jsFleetController",
    ['$scope', 'trucksService',
        function ($scope, trucksService) {

                $scope.trucks = trucksService.getTrucks();

    }]);
```

---

**trucksService.js**

```
"use strict";

angular.module("jsFleet").service("trucksService",

       function () {
           this.getTrucks = function () {
               return trucks;
           };
           this.getTruck = function (truckID) {
               for (var i = 0, len = trucks.length; i < len; i++) {
                   if (trucks[i].truckID === parseInt(truckID)) {
                       return trucks[i];
                   }
               }
               return {};
           };
           var trucks = [
               {
                   truckID: 1,
                   status: Running,
                   destination: WPG,
                   alerts: Nothing
               },
                   {
                       truckID: 5,
                       status: Running,
                       destination: WPG,
                       alerts: Nothing
                   },
                   {
                       truckID: 2,
                       status: Running,
                       destination: WPG,
                       alerts: Nothing
                   },
                   {
                       truckID: 3,
                       status: Running,
                       destination: WPG,
                       alerts: Nothing
                   },
                   {
                       truckID: 4,
                       status: Running,
                       destination: WPG,
                       alerts: Nothing
                   }
           ];

       });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `controller:` definition in your route config is incorrect.  The `controller` argument expects the name of a controller to be specified, not the file that the controller is in.

Instead of:

```js
.when('/fleet', {

    controller: 'ext-modules/fleet/jsFleetController.js',
    templateUrl: 'ext-modules/fleet/jsFleetTemplate.html'
  })
  .when('/drivers', {
    controller: 'ext-modules/drivers/jsDriversController.js',
    templateUrl: 'ext-modules/drivers/jsDriversTemplate.html'

  })
```

you should have:

```js
.when('/fleet', {
    controller: 'jsFleetController',
    templateUrl: 'ext-modules/fleet/jsFleetTemplate.html'
  })
  .when('/drivers', {
    controller: 'jsDriversController',
    templateUrl: 'ext-modules/drivers/jsDriversTemplate.html'

  })
```

Also looking at your scripts, your scripts appear to be loaded in the wrong order.  Each JavaScript file must be loaded *before* any other JavaScript can reference it.  The JavaScript files that reference other modules should, therefore, be the last things loaded.

try changing the order of your script files, i.e.:

```html
<script src="ext-modules/fleet/jsFleetModule.js"></script>
<script src="ext-modules/fleet/jsFleetController.js"></script>

<script src="ext-modules/drivers/jsDriversModule.js"></script>
<script src="ext-modules/drivers/jsDriversController.js"></script>

<script src="services/trucksService.js"></script>

<script src="main/appModule.js"></script>
<script src="main/appRouting.js"></script>
```

Comment: After making the changes to, I am getting same error. Any other ideas please?

Comment: Yes. I tried removing the script from the index.html to, still its giving the same error. I don't know from where it is calling the script files.

Comment: Okay, I changed the order of Java scripts in index.html. Now am getting the error as "Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'jsFleetController.js' is not a function, got undefined"

Comment: check the first part of the answer again.  refer to the controller by it's name, not it's filename.  Try `jsFleetController` instead of `jsFleetController.js`.

Comment: Okay I did that. Now am getting as "ReferenceError: Running is not defined"

Comment: well, that would be a different question.  Your truck service has `status: Running` in multiple places.  Is `Running` supposed to be an ENUM, or did you mean `status: 'Running'`, or something else?  Either way, the fact that you are getting that error now indicates that your controller is indeed loaded, and loading it's dependencies, and this question is solved.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you very much all working good now. Appreciate it !! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the problem is in your routing when you are specifying the controller you just need to give it the name not the url:

```
controller: 'ext-modules/fleet/jsFleetController.js',
```

should change to

```
controller: 'jsFleetController'
```

Comment: After making the changes to, I am getting same error. Any other ideas please?